# How can make an auto-clicker work when I hold the left click mouse bottom?

Tags: python, pyautogui

How can make an auto-clicker work when I hold the left click mouse bottom ?

It work well when I make it work with an other key. But when holding the left click it does't work.
The problem that I face is that when It detect a left click,  the `pyautogui.click()` make a click which act like If I had realeased the holding button so it make the autoclicker stop.

main.py

```
import win32api
import pyautogui


state_left = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01) 
pyautogui.PAUSE = 0.06
stop_key_state = win32api.GetKeyState(0x50) 

while True: 
    a = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01) 
    b = win32api.GetKeyState(0x50)

    if b < 0:
        False

    if a != state_left:  # Button state changed 
        state_left = a 
        if a < 0:
            print("Left Button Pressed")

        else:
            print("Left Button Released")
```